# PhantomJS - Javascript fill out and press okay on confirm alert

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, alert, headless-browser

I am trying to automate a process in PhantomJS. Part of the process has a JavaScript Confirm Box that pops up that asks for a username and password. You can click "okay" or "cancel". Is there any way for me to do this using PhantomJS. I see in the docs three functions onPrompt(), onAlert(),and onConfirm(). I have tried all three of these just to console log when the pop up opens and none of them are giving me any console logs when I am fairly certain that it is opening. Anyone else had this problem?

```
page.onConfirm = function() {
  console.log('CONFIRM');
  return true; // `true` === pressing the "OK" button, `false` === pressing the "Cancel" button
};
```